# How to Access File Content from C# HTTPWebRequest with AutoRedirect

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to call a URL that should return an authentication token.
Data is posted to the URL and after a number of redirects returns a JSON object with a token.
I'm using C# and WPF.

Here is the excerpt from what I am doing:

```
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
            request1.Method = "POST";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String boundary = "-----------------------------1721856231228";
            foreach (elem in elems)
            {
                String nameStr = elem.GetAttribute("name");
                if (nameStr != null && nameStr.Length != 0)
                {
                    String valueStr = elem.GetAttribute("value");
                    sb.Append("\r\n" + boundary + "\r\n");
                    sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + nameStr + "\"" + "\r\n");
                    sb.Append("\r\n");
                    sb.Append(valueStr);
                }
            }
            sb.Append("\r\n--" + boundary + "--" + "\r\n");
            String postData1 = sb.ToString();
            request1.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3";
            request1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36";
            request1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; boundary=" + boundary;
            request1.ContentLength = postData1.Length;
            request1.KeepAlive = true;
            request1.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(request1.GetRequestStream());
            w.Write(postData1);
            w.Close();

            HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream());
            String responseText1 = reader1.ReadToEnd();
            reader1.Close();
            response1.Close();
```

But the response doesn't contain the JSON with a token.
I am using Fiddler and can pause at the end of the above code and the URI that should have the JSON hasn't been called.  I can continue executing other code in the debugger, and then later, Fiddler will show the URI as having been called and a File Download popup lets me then download a JSON file that contains the token.
I don't want the popup and I want to be able to capture the JSON data programmatically.

I found by adding the following line to the end of the code above, and just executing that line in the debugger, that Fiddler will report that the token URL has been called (and I can see in Fiddler the correct JSON response):

```
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

But I don't know how to access this response or how to short-circuit the file download popup from not happening.

Maybe something in the KeepAlive setting would help?

Answer (score 0):

try newtonsoft to read 
using Newtonsoft.Json

```
TokenModel tokenModel;

StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(response1.GetResponseStream());
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(reader1))
{    
 tokenModel = serializer.Deserialize<TokenModel>(reader);
}
```

Reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm

Or you can use following complete request with response with HttpClient

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("your url");
        int _TimeoutSec = 90;
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, _TimeoutSec);
        string _ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";            
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));

       //if you have any content to send use following keyValuePair

        var kv = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        kv.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "value"));
        kv.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "value"));


        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "your url") { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kv) };
        var responseAsyn = client.SendAsync(req);
        var response = responseAsyn.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        TokenModel tokenResponse = new TokenModel();
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(responseString);
        }
```

Comment: I tried, but the final URL with the JSON response had still not been returned.

Comment: I updated the complete request with HttpClient, this is working code with any post request which return json